# crashes on CM11 and mysterious low space issues

Tags: adb, internal-storage, sd-card, cyanogenmod

I have several crashes (eg. can't start whatsapp, google play) sometimes clearing cache work.
it's seems there is a race on storage the app that gets first cache works others did not.

I tried to install telegram from .apk I get from my other phone I got this "No space left on device"
but there is good space (I guess 1.4GB). could it be some permission/ownership problem?

kindly find some debug information below which indicates that there is good enough space

```
[alsadi@localhost adt]$ ./sdk/platform-tools/adb root
adbd is already running as root
[alsadi@localhost adt]$ ./sdk/platform-tools/adb install org.telegram.messenger-1.apk 
failed to copy 'org.telegram.messenger-1.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/org.telegram.messenger-1.apk': No space left on device
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/org.telegram.messenger-1.apk, No such file or directory
[alsadi@localhost adt]$ ./sdk/platform-tools/adb shell
root@galaxysl:/ # df /data/local/tmp/
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/data/local/tmp/         1.9G   478.7M     1.4G   4096
root@galaxysl:/ # ls -ld /data                                                 
drwxrwx--x system   system            2014-02-28 14:54 data
root@galaxysl:/ # ls -ld /data/local                                           
drwxr-x--x root     root              2014-01-01 16:07 local
root@galaxysl:/ # ls -ld /data/local/tmp                                       
drwxrwx--x shell    shell             2014-02-13 21:28 tmp
root@galaxysl:/ # df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   226.1M   136.0K   226.0M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         226.1M     0.0K   226.1M   4096
/mnt/asec              226.1M     0.0K   226.1M   4096
/mnt/obb               226.1M     0.0K   226.1M   4096
/mnt/fuse              226.1M     0.0K   226.1M   4096
/efs                    12.5M     6.8M     5.7M   4096
/radio                  18.5M    14.3M     4.2M   4096
/system                433.5M   359.4M    74.1M   4096
/cache                 293.2M     5.3M   288.0M   4096
/data                    1.9G   478.7M     1.4G   4096
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1    15.1G     8.6G     6.5G   32768
/storage/sdcard1        15.1G     8.6G     6.5G   32768
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard0     1.5G     1.2G   361.7M   32768
/mnt/secure/asec         1.5G     1.2G   361.7M   32768
/storage/sdcard0         1.5G     1.2G   361.7M   32768
/mnt/asec/com.backflipstudios.android.ninjumpdeluxe-1    40.0M    38.4M     1.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.google.zxing.client.android-1     2.0M   708.0K     1.3M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad-2    20.0M    18.2M     1.8M   4096
/mnt/asec/jmaster.supaplex.android-1     3.0M     1.8M     1.2M   4096
/mnt/asec/info.obada.abjad-1    12.0M    10.5M     1.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.imangi.templerun-1    25.0M    23.5M     1.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.koushikdutta.rommanager-1     5.0M     3.3M     1.7M   4096
/mnt/asec/org.telegram.messenger-1    11.0M     9.5M     1.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.imvideo-1    24.0M    22.7M     1.3M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.bigduckgames.flowbridges-2    21.0M    19.3M     1.7M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v7_neon-2    16.0M    14.8M     1.2M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.google.android.apps.unveil-1     5.0M     3.3M     1.8M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.bti.myPiano-1     8.0M     6.5M     1.5M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.kauf.talking.mytalkingbabymusicstar-1    45.0M    44.0M   984.0K   4096
/mnt/asec/com.pumkin.fun-1    13.0M    11.9M     1.1M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.polarbit.rthunder2lite-1    33.0M    31.2M     1.8M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.skype.raider-1    37.0M    35.2M     1.8M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.game.MarbleSaga-1    27.0M    25.3M     1.7M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.google.android.apps.translate-1     6.0M     4.4M     1.6M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.kiloo.subwaysurf-2    31.0M    29.4M     1.6M   4096
/mnt/asec/org.zwanoo.android.speedtest-1    15.0M    13.3M     1.7M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.adobe.reader-1    12.0M    11.0M     1.0M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.guidedways.iQuran-1    16.0M    14.4M     1.6M   4096
/mnt/asec/info.obada.ashkalalwan-1     5.0M     3.4M     1.6M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.clapfootgames.laserwarsfree-1    26.0M    24.0M     2.0M   4096
/mnt/asec/ua.co.cts.sideup-1     6.0M     4.1M     1.9M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.sand.airdroid-1    11.0M     9.7M     1.3M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.rovio.angrybirdsrio-1    43.0M    36.2M     6.8M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.gamestar.pianoperfect-1    15.0M    13.9M     1.1M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.bigduckgames.flow-2    21.0M    19.3M     1.7M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.bestcoolfungames.antsmasher-1     6.0M     4.7M     1.3M   4096
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your df output, you only have **361.7M** left not 1.4GB. All the Apps are installed on the local storage i.e. sdcard0 by default. This means that when your internal storage runs out of space, you won't be able to install any new Apps.

You can try one (or all) of the following:

1. uninstall unnecessary Apps;
2. from recovery, wipe cache and dalvik cache partitions;
3. delete the .odex file if it is already there.

For the last .odex file, the instructions from the XDA [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1834105) are, open the terminal and:

```
su
cd /data
cd /app
ls
rm (packagename.odex)
```

Yet another alternative solution is to manually delete the app folder in /data/app-lib. See more details in this XDA [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2443267).

Comment: can it be switched to sdcard1 instead of sdcard0? how?

Comment: In short, yes. Apps like [App2SD](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.app2sd) can move apps and [Titanium Backup](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-technical-faq.html#apps2sd-data2sd) can move App data. It's quite tricky process and I must warn do at your own risk, a lengthy tutorial and discussion can be found at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726014). Good luck.